# How to use Double Match function in Excel (2010)

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I'm working on a report on Excel. It contains a lot of Data in a Table. now I want to filter the data according to our requirements 
[image: "Sample Image"]

As you can see in the image, there are three columns: ID, Length, and Count. one ID has different lengths in which some of them are same (like in ID # D123456 there are three 111 lengths.) now I want to count these type of IDs only one time. In simple, in one type of ID, every different length should be counted only once. Please help me in this problem as it will be a great kind of favor.

Comment: Starting in `C1`: `=N(NOT(COUNTIFS(A$1:A1,A1,B$1:B1,B1)-1))` will do it ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming data in columns A and B, using countifs. Enter the following in C2 and drag down:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS($A$1:A1,A2,$B$1:B1,B2)=0,1,0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this
for the first row in count enter 1

for the next row use this formula and drag down

```
C2 =IF(SUMPRODUCT((A$2:A2=A3)*(B$2:B2=B3))>0,0,1)
```

[image]